# looping array of pointers to free them makes program crash in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void printarray(int* array, int arraysize){
    for (int i = 0; i<arraysize; i++){
        printf("%d\n", *array);
        array++;
    }
}

void printStrArray(char** array, int arraysize){
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<arraysize; i++){
        j = 0;
        while (array[i][j] != '\0'){
            printf("%c", array[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int isStringInArray(char* string, char** stringArray, int arrayLen){ // returns 1 if string is contained in the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++){
        if (strcmp(string, stringArray[i]) == 0){
            //printf("%s is equal to %s %d\n", string, stringArray[i], i);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int lenstring(char* string){ // checks string length (works only if string has null character at the end.)
    char currchar = string[0];
    int strlen = 0;
    while (currchar != '\0'){
        strlen++;
        currchar = string[strlen];
    }
    return strlen;
}

char** riassemble(char* stringa){
    char** riassembleds = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
    char* charLen = malloc(sizeof(char));
    riassembleds[0] = charLen;
    int riassembledLen = 1;
    int stringalen = lenstring(stringa);
    char tempstring[stringalen];
    strcpy(tempstring, stringa);

    for (int i = 0; i < stringalen; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < stringalen; j++){
            tempstring[i] = stringa[j];
            tempstring[j] = stringa[i];
            //printf("%s\n", tempstring);
            if (isStringInArray(tempstring, riassembleds, riassembledLen) == 0){
                riassembleds = realloc(riassembleds, (riassembledLen+1)*sizeof(char*));
                riassembledLen++;
                riassembleds[riassembledLen-1] = calloc(stringalen, sizeof(char));
                printf("%p\n", riassembleds[riassembledLen-1]);
                strcpy(riassembleds[riassembledLen-1], tempstring);
            }
            strcpy(tempstring, stringa);
        }
    }
    *charLen = (char)riassembledLen;

    riassembleds[0] = charLen; /*return the array with the length of the it casted into a char pointer as the first element*/
    return riassembleds;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char** array = riassemble("ciao");

    int arraylen = (int)(*(array[0]));
    printf("\n%d\n", arraylen);
    printStrArray(array, arraylen);

    for (int i=0; i<arraylen; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);    
    return 0;
}
```

i'm making a function that returns an array of pointers to a char, in which the first element is a pointer that points to the length of the array casted into a char.

When i try to free the elements in the array with

```
    char** array = riassemble("ciao"); /*Creates the array*/

    int arraylen = (int)(*(array[0])); /*Gets the length*/

    for (int i=0; i<arraylen; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
```

The program crashes after trying to free the second element of the array which is defined here:

```
riassembleds = realloc(riassembleds, (riassembledLen+1)*sizeof(char*));
riassembledLen++;
riassembleds[riassembledLen-1] = calloc(stringalen, sizeof(char));
printf("%p\n", riassembleds[riassembledLen-1]);
strcpy(riassembleds[riassembledLen-1], tempstring);
```

I really don't understand why this happens, one thing i noticed is that if i print the pointers that it's trying to free, they're not the same as when i print them right after allocating them in the riassemble function, but other than that i have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

edit: i was wrong about the fact that they're not the same, they actually are, i got confused.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce: https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/EthicalHurtfulCommands#main.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `lenstring` will return the length of the string without the terminating null character.

Therefore, the line

```
char tempstring[stringalen];
```

will create an array `tempstring`that is sufficient in size to store the string `stringa` **without** the terminating null character.

However, the function call

```
strcpy(tempstring, stringa);
```

requires that `tempstring` is large enough to store `stringa` **with** the terminating null character. You are therefore writing to `tempstring` out of bounds, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In order to fix this, I recommend that you change the line

```
char tempstring[stringalen];
```

to:

```
char tempstring[stringalen+1];
```

The line

```
riassembleds[riassembledLen-1] = calloc(stringalen, sizeof(char));
```

has the same problem, as it only allocates sufficient space **without** the terminating null character, which causes the line

```
strcpy(riassembleds[riassembledLen-1], tempstring);
```

to invoke undefined behavior for the same reason.

Therefore, the line

```
riassembleds[riassembledLen-1] = calloc(stringalen, sizeof(char));
```

should be changed to

```
riassembleds[riassembledLen-1] = calloc(stringalen+1, sizeof(char));
```

I was able to find these errors very easily by using [AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) on your program.